# Globalization of Windows Forms Application with Arabic Support

Tags: vb.net

I am using Windows Forms Application that supports both Arabic and English languages....
The problem is if i put the controls like (TextBox and Label) on form itself they get Layout RightToLeft and also become right align means label went to right side and textbox in left side)....
But when i put these controls inside of a GroupBox or Table then textbox itself become right align ...i means cursor inside of text box............but controls don't flip from left to right......Label remains on left side and textbox on right side....

i want to flip the controls.........label must go to right...same like Forms ControlBox is flipping.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to design your own control (say GlobalizedLabelTextBox) that flips label and textbox depending on the current UI culture. The form itself will not flip from just RightToLeft.